How do I authenticate Firebase phone auth with real phone numbers on production website
Please I need help to make my phone authentication work in the production website. When I use it on development with the test numbers it goes through, but when I deploy to vercel and I try to use real phone numbers I get this error

Error sending OTP:  FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/error-code:-39).

I have upgraded my account and added my vercel domain to the authorized domain, it still does not work. Please I really need help to sort this out.
This is the vercel domain
easycargo-web.vercel.app I have added it to the firebase authorized domain.
And this is actually for the web platform
